# Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible - centos 7 plask 12

Tags: apache, magento, symlink, centos7

Using `centos7` and `plask-12`, without `SUEXEC` installed, permissions double checked, and with a disabled firewall, I get:

> AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/vhosts/bargainblast.co.uk/boomdeal.co.uk/skin, referer: boomdeal.co.uk/
>
> Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible:
>   /var/www/vhosts/bargainblast.co.uk/boomdeal.co.uk/js, referer:
>   boomdeal co uk/

I am trying to run the Magento multi-store functionality. The main store is `bragainblast co uk` and the second store is `boomdeal co uk`.

The second website is not loading css and js because of this symbolic link issue.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32rEe.jpg)

Comment: I think you have not configure url store wise, If it possible then attached screenshot of your configuration (store wise)

Comment: Hi SimBeez i uploaded screenshot please have a look thanks